# getting Invalid Reference Format while executing docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While executing below script,

```
sudo docker run -volume "$PWD:/build" -volume "~/.m2:/root/.m2" -volume "~/.build:/root/.build"`
```

i am getting below error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

OS using is ubuntu-18. Followed some stackoverflow threads, but missing something.

Comment: I think `~` is the issue?

Comment: @Intellidroid No , i tried that too

Comment: Where is your image_name?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> sudo docker run -volume "$PWD:/build" -volume "~/.m2:/root/.m2" -volume "~/.build:/root/.build"
> ```

Your command has several issues:

- `-volume "$PWD:/build"` is not proper syntax, you should use `--volume "$PWD:/build"` or `-v "$PWD:/build"`
- you are missing an image name: `docker run` require you to specify which image to run, for example `maven:3-jdk-8`
- it seems you are trying to run a Maven build, you should also specify the working directory with `-w` and Maven goals

For example:

```
sudo docker run -v "$PWD:/build" -w /build -v "~/.m2:/root/.m2" -v "~/.build:/root/.build" maven:3-jdk-8 mvn clean package
```